# how to set Robots.txt files for subdomains?

Tags: robots.txt, subdomain

I have a subdomain eg blog.example.com and i want this domain not to index by Google or any other search engine. I put my robots.txt file in 'blog' folder in the server with following configuration:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Would it be fine to not to index by Google?

A few days before my site:blog.example.com shows 931 links but now it is displaying 1320 pages. I am wondering if my robots.txt file is correct then why Google is indexing my domain.

If i am doing anything wrong please correct me.

Answer (score 1):

Rahul,

Not sure if your robots.txt is verbatim, but generally the directives are on TWO lines:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

This file must be accessible from http://blog.example.com/robots.txt - if it is not accessible from that URL, the search engine spider will not find it.

If you have pages that have already been indexed by Google, you can also try using Google Webmaster Tools to manually remove pages from the index.

Comment: http://blog.example.com/robots.txt is looking fine as i already mentioned and also look like as you told but the issue is that google spider is still indexing my pages.

Answer (score 0):

This question is actually about how to prevent indexing of a subdomain, here your robots file is actually preventing your site from being noindexed.

> Don’t use a robots.txt file as a means to hide your web pages from Google search results.

[Introduction to robots.txt: What is a robots.txt file used for?](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/robots/intro#what-is-a-robots.txt-file-used-for)  Google Search Central Documentation

> For the noindex directive to be effective, the page or resource must not be blocked by a robots.txt file, and it has to be otherwise accessible to the crawler. If the page is blocked by a robots.txt file or the crawler can’t access the page, the crawler will never see the noindex directive, and the page can still appear in search results, for example if other pages link to it.

[Block Search indexing with noindex](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/block-indexing) Google Search Central Documentation